# php treating stdClass as user defined class

Tags: php

I am creating a new stdClass using

```
$usrobj=new stdClass();
```

and it gives me this error

```
PHP Warning:  require_once(objects/User/stdClass.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...
```

seems that php is treating stdClass as user defined class

the same happens to

```
$db=new mysqli();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you're using a namespace. e.g.:

```
<?php
namespace Foo\Bar;
$obj = new stdClass; // Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Foo\Bar\stdClass' not found
```

in combination with an autoloader that tries to load files from the `objects/User/` directory when that class is not found.

To use any of the global classes, you will need to put a `\` before the class name to specify that you are trying to access a global class, and not a class from the current namespace:

```
$usrobj=new \stdClass();
$db=new \mysqli();
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be namespace issue(related to a misuse of PHP 5.3 namespaces).

```
$o= new \stdClass();
$o->a = 'new object';
```

Same thing you can use with mysql object.